# Two Page Numbers in One Page

Tags: header-footer, lyx, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am using LyX to layout a collection of essays.

There is one page-number-position per spread in the design. Please find the example below. Instead of showing `59`, is it possible to show `58—59`? I am using `fancyhead` to define the current example. my code as follow:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{fancy}
\fancyhead{}%
\fancyfoot{}%
\fancyhead[CE]{\rmfamily \small \leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\rmfamily \small\thepage }
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\rmfamily \small }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

[image: Example of the task]

Comment: I think it would be funny to display 58-59 on the right page. This would esentially mean that this page has two pagenumbers. Instead I would either drop the page number in the footer and use `CO,CE` as options for`\thepage`, or I'd push it in the margin, but again display it on both pages

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've used similar "dirty trick" before, and they do not anything when done correctly ;) Of course, you can use `tempcntra` to avoid manipulation with `page` counter, but it seems not ot be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the corresponding line to

```
\fancyhead[CO]{%
  \rmfamily\small
  \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
  \thepage
  \addtocounter{page}{1}%
  --\thepage
}
```

We simply substract `1` from coutner `page`, print the page number, and add this `1` back so that we can print the current page number and we do not mess the page numbering.

Comment: If you needed special treatment of page one so that it does not show `0--1`, don't hesitate to request it!