# page number to cover several numbers, i.e. page page 1, 2, 3/4, 5-8, and 9

Tags: page-numbering, indexing

I'm interested to have several page number's refer to one page?

Here's an example illustrating what I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{3}
\subsection{Introduction}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{5} % what I would like to be able to write {4/5}
\subsection{Something}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{7}
\subsection{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

this obliviously give this index,
[image: current index]

what I would like to do is to, e.g., set `\setcounter{page}{4/5}` and get is something like,
[image: goaaaaoooooallll2]

possible also with the option to set `\setcounter{page}{5-8}`

I generated the above using this code (and then deleted some pages)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Huge\arabic{page}}
% 1, 2, 3/4, 5-8, and 9
\begin{document}
{\Huge \tableofcontents}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\subsection{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{2}
\subsection{Foo}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{3} % here I would like to be able to write \setcounter{page}{3/4}
\subsection{Something}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
4
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{5} % here I would like to be able to write \setcounter{page}{5-8}
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
6
\newpage
7
\newpage
9
\newpage
\subsection{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For page ranges in the table of contents please have a look at these answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145206/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170367/134144

Comment: @leandriis, Thank you for your comment. I did look at those answers, what they do is tweaking the index to `summarize’ a range of page numbers in the index. That’s not _exactly_ what I am looking to do. What I am looking for is some way to _cram_ several (virtual?) pages onto one page. Which then would be reflected in the index (and look like th two answer you point to). I’ll update my question.

Comment: For page number ranges on the pages of a document I found the following solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68425/134144, which can be easily adapted to your task. However, using this approach, the page numbers in the toc are not shown as page ranges and I have not been able to figure out how to overcome this.

Comment: Even if it is interesting to find a technical solution to your question, I like to remind that the reader has to interpret it. Often the value of the table of contents is overrated.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein, that's exactly the issue I am currently struggling with. I am definitely interested to have the reader interpret the pages as `3/4`, `5-8`, etc. To me most readers seem to be quite flexible. I have PDF documents where the first pages are roman, i.e `i`, `ii`, ... and the following pages are arabic, i.e.  `1`, `2`, ... I can also generate PDFs that the reader reads with non-continues pages, but maybe `3/4`, `5-8`, etc. is impossible.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

With the package `everypage` you can create a macro to specify a custom page number which is automatically reset after the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Specify the default page format:
\newcommand*{\thepageformat}{\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Huge\thepageformat}

%% Automatically reset the page format to default on every page:
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{
    \global\def\thepageformat{\arabic{page}}
}

%% A macro to set the page "number" manually for the current page:
\newcommand*{\custompage}[2][1]{
    %% use the optional argument to specify the number of pages in your range
    \AddThispageHook{\global\def\thepageformat{#2}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\addtocounter{page}{#1}}
}


\begin{document}
    {\Huge \tableofcontents}
    \subsection{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
    \newpage

    \subsection{Foo}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage

    \custompage[2]{3/4} %% range 3-4 (2 pages)
    \subsection{Something}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage

    \custompage[4]{5--8} %% range 5-8 (4 pages)
    \subsection{Bar}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage

    \subsection{Conclusion}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Update: now the table of contents is also correct.

[image: Toc]

**Edit:** 
With the macro

```
\newcommand*{\custompagetoc}[3][1]{ %% Usage: \custompagetoc[numpages]{page number}{toc page number}
    \AddThispageHook{
        \global\def\thepageformat{#3} %% for the toc
        \def\thepageformat{#2} %% for the page
        \addtocounter{page}{-1}\addtocounter{page}{#1}
    }
}
```

you can also have different page numbers in the toc than on the page itself:

```
\custompagetoc[4]{5--8}{5+} %% on the page: "5–8", in the toc: "5+", advance counter by 4 pages instead of 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a counter to a range. But you can change the representation of the page number (I leave the \Huge as it was in your example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Huge\arabic{page}}
% 1, 2, 3/4, 5-8, and 9
\begin{document}
{\Huge \tableofcontents}
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\subsection{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
%\setcounter{page}{2}
\subsection{Foo}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\renewcommand\thepage{\Huge3/4}
\subsection{Something}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\renewcommand\thepage{\Huge\arabic{page}}
4
\newpage
\renewcommand\thepage{\Huge5-8}
\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\renewcommand\thepage{\Huge\arabic{page}}
6
\newpage
7
\newpage
9
\newpage
\subsection{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a command `\newVirtualPage` (without parameters) which can be used like `\newpage` but which has no visual effect except for an influence on the page number. This would avoid the need to hardcode page numbers and avoid possible inconsistencies.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{NumberVirtualPages}


% use this to create a new virtual page
% use it several times if you want several virtual pages
% the page number is adjusted automatically
\newcommand{\newVirtualPage}{%
    \stepcounter{NumberVirtualPages}%
    \stepcounter{page}%
}


% format to be used for page numbers
\newcommand*{\thePageFormat}{\arabic{page}}


% initialize \theRealPage
\xdef\theRealPage{\thePageFormat}


% set \pagenumber at every page depending on NumberVirtualPages
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{%
    % define \pagenumber
    \xdef\thepage{%
        \ifnum 0=\theNumberVirtualPages\relax
            \theRealPage
        \else \ifnum 1=\theNumberVirtualPages\relax
            \theRealPage/\thePageFormat%
        \else
            \theRealPage--\thePageFormat%
        \fi \fi
    }%
    % set \theRealPage to next page number
    \addtocounter{page}{+1}%
    \xdef\theRealPage{\thePageFormat}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    % reset NumberVirtualPages
    \setcounter{NumberVirtualPages}{0}%
}



% ========== TEST ==========

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{intro}%
    \lipsum[1]
    \newpage

    \section{Foo}
    \label{foo}%
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage


    \section{Bar}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \label{bar-1}%
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \newVirtualPage
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \label{bar-2}%
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}%
    \newpage

    \section{Another Section}
    \label{a-1}%
    \lipsum[1]
    \newVirtualPage
    \bigskip
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \label{a-2}%
        \lipsum[1-1]
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \newVirtualPage
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \label{a-3}%
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}%

    \newpage

    \section{Conclusion}
    \label{end}
    \newcommand{\testref}[1]{section~\ref{#1} on page~\pageref{#1}}
    It started with \testref{intro}, followed by \testref{foo}.
    It got interesting in \testref{bar-1} and \testref{bar-2}.
    As shown in \testref{a-1}, \testref{a-2} and \testref{a-3} the page number looks different when having more virtual pages.
    In the end it is even possible to reference \testref{end}.
\end{document}
```

[image: table of contents]
[image: references]